# Send / Receive Java Objects through Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to send Java Object through Kafka and receive them as Java Object as well. I thought the following configuration for ProducerFactory and ConsumerFactory will suffice, but I am receiving payload as org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord. What do I need to change in ConsumerFactory?

Consumer Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    JsonDeserializer<Object> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Object.class);

    deserializer.addTrustedPackages("*");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> headersKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
  ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
  factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory("headers"));
  return factory;
}
```

}

Producer Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, Object> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

}

Comment: You should use your actual class type, not Object... And the consumer record holds more than just your data

Comment: I want to make a generic interface, that's why I do not want to use class type

Comment: That's not possible without reflection. You also shouldn't share consumer instances over different topics and types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you mentioned you can get the java object using the value of the consumer record.

```
 @component
 public class Listener {

  @kafkaListener
  void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, Car> record) {
  Car car = record.value();
  }
 }
```

by accessing the record.value(). You can get the relevant java object for that you have to have to deserializers in place.

Answer (score 1):

> I am receiving payload as org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord

Have you looked at the Javadoc for that class and noticed the `.value()` method?

FWIW, Avro or Protobuf serializers are more efficient at sending objects than JSON

Comment: Ok, I will try replacing the json serializer.